# текущий город Яндекс.Карты JS

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как узнать название города\населённого пункта, который сейчас отображён на карте у пользователя? т.е. Изначально я определяю его координаты, выставляю центр по карте и всё хорошо, но как можно узнать, что пользователь открыл теперь другой город и просматривает его?

Answer (score 1):

В песочнице есть пример где показано как находить составные части ответа от геокодера, например город: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode 
Также есть пример где показано как узнавать адрес в центре карты:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control
Чтобы это делать при каждом сдвиге карты можно подписаться на событие изменения границ карты boundschange https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-boundschange
Но надо понимать что за один день в бесплатной версии вы можете делать не больше 25000 запросов к геокодеру.